# How do I access the means and covariances using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to access the means after applying EM on a GMM, using code detailed here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.3/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html

My code:

```
import cv2,cv 

em = cv2.EM(nclusters=4)
result = em.train(gaussData)

print em.getMeans()
```

but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'cv2.EM' object has no attribute 'getMeans'
```

I am using opencv 2.4.5 (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/ml/doc/expectation_maximization.html) which only lists Algorithm::get() and Algorithm::set() functions for C++

How do I access the means and covariances using Python ?!

Comment: What do you see when you type `help(em)`?

Comment: Ahh, that solved it..it showed me the list of functions inherited from algorithm which is what I needed. Didn't realize this 'help' feature existed, just shows the importance of formally learning the language I suppose. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: It would be good to answer your own question so that future users can find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got over this was to simply put a

```
print help(em)
```

in my code. This printed all the data members associated with em, and I was able to find what I needed!